# Update on Multiple columns using join in AWS-Redshift error

Tags: amazon-redshift

The below code is throwing error as.
column "t" of relation "producttest" does not exists.
`

```
update dbo.producttest
set t.brand_code = s.mtl_brand_desc,
t.prodname = s.pname
from raw.data as s inner join dbo.producttest as t
on t.Chain = CASE s.chain WHEN 1 THEN 'EPRC'
                            WHEN 3 THEN 'FSC'
                            WHEN 7 THEN 'CM' END
and t.item_number = replace( s.item_id, '-', '')`

Please help.
```

The code is working fine on sql server

Comment: ah! just remove alias appear next to set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE dbo.producttest
SET brand_code = s.mtl_brand_desc,
    prodname = s.pname
FROM raw.data AS s
    INNER JOIN dbo.producttest AS t
        ON t.Chain = CASE s.chain
                         WHEN 1 THEN
                             'EPRC'
                         WHEN 3 THEN
                             'FSC'
                         WHEN 7 THEN
                             'CM'
                     END
           AND t.item_number = REPLACE(s.item_id, '-', '')
```

Alternative way you don't need to specify the table that you are updating again on the `JOIN` usually

```sql
UPDATE dbo.producttest
SET brand_code = s.mtl_brand_desc,
    prodname = s.pname
FROM raw.data AS s
        WHERE dbo.producttest.Chain = CASE s.chain
                         WHEN 1 THEN
                             'EPRC'
                         WHEN 3 THEN
                             'FSC'
                         WHEN 7 THEN
                             'CM'
                     END
           AND dbo.producttest.item_number = REPLACE(s.item_id, '-', '')
```